# matplotlib funcanimation save issue

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I have been trying some animation recently using matplotlib animations. It has been going great, i create an ffmpeg writer and save it as a video file. However i face an issue whenever the function that FuncAnimation calls returns more than one object.

Below is a small snippet of my code base. When I return both im0 and im1, the video file created only has im1 , although the plt.show command works as expected ( showing both the videos ). If i return just a single im0, then it works as expected. IT also works as expected if i return both im0 and im1 with alpha=0.5.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening underneath the hood?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
def animate(i):
    im0=ax.imshow(np.ma.masked_array(imgl[i][:,:,0], mask=get_blob(i)),cmap='cubehelix')

    im1=ax.imshow(imgl[(i-100)%len(imgl)][:,:,0],cmap='cubehelix')

    return [im1,im0]



ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200,
                              interval=10, blit=True,repeat=False)
ani.save('ps.mp4', writer=writer)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `fig`?  The output from `plt.subplots()` or something?  Could you include that as well?

Comment: Yes added that bit too.

Comment: Try removing blitting (but that should not affect the saving)?  There is nothing that strikes me as immediately funny about this and it _should _ work just fine.  Can you re-work this as a runable example (plot random data).

Comment: And where do you set the alpha?

Comment: I experimented with this some more. I added the line

fig.savefig("/Users/richieabraham/tests/1/masks%d.png"%i)

to see the images and even these images had the error i.e the images had no trace of im0 and they just had im1 in them.


If I set im0 as ax.imshow(np.ma.masked_array(imgl[i][:,:,0], mask=get_blob(i)),cmap='cubehelix', alpha=0.5) and im1 also in the same manner, then I see both of them in the final images that I have saved.